# Flickity sync and nav hover event

Tags: jquery, css, flickity

I'm looking to change the main carousel on the hover event of a nav item, using asNavFor.
I am a beginner with jQuery and I can't get the code below to work with my installation. I don't know how to do it.

the solution found on GitHub

https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/LJYxmZ

```
$carouselNav.on( 'mouseover', '.carousel-cell', function( event ) {
  var index = $( event.currentTarget ).index();
  $carouselMain.flickity( 'select', index );
});
```

My installation with npm

```
 const
    $main =document.querySelector('.carousel-main'),
    $nav = document.querySelector('.carousel-nav')
    ;

  var Flickity = require('flickity');
  require('flickity-fade');
  require('flickity-as-nav-for');

  var flkty = new Flickity( $main, {
    fade:true,
    pageDots: false,
    draggable: false,
    contain: true,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    wrapAround: true
  });
  
    var flktynav = new Flickity( $nav, {
    asNavFor: $main,
    fade: false,
    draggable: false,
    pageDots: false,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    contain: true
  });
```

Comment: what exactly is the error? did you do any debugging?

Comment: Hi Jasie, I don't know how to make this work with my current installation. When I use its code nothing works and I don't see any errors in my browser console. I use jquery on another part of the page and it works fine

Comment: you have not disclosed what effect your code is supposed to have and what exactly it does instead. to me, the requirement and specific problem are not clear.

Comment: Actually my code works very well. I have a main slider and a second slider for navigation. It works on click, only I would like to be able to make it work on hover, exactly like the codepen demonstration.
But I can't adapt the jquery code from the codepen demo to my current installation. 
I would like to be able to make the code snippet from the provided solution work 
with my code, but being a beginner with jquery I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: did you do any debugging? what's in $main, $nav, Flickity, flkty, flktynav? did you try writing sth to the browser console to make sure 'mouseover' fires correctly? (do you know how to debug code?)